# Using jQuery click event to toggle element on page using "this"

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I am attempting to use a click event to toggle an element that is not a child or parent of the selected item. I need to use "this" because there are several different elements I'd like to use the same jQuery click event that contain the same class. I have attempted every other solution I could find on SO but none of them seem to be working for me.

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="row name-header">
    <span class="col-xs-12">Tracy King</span>
</div>
  <div class="center" id="portrait-row">
    <img class="myFace" src="images/myface.jpg" alt="portrait">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div class="row-panel">
          <p>About Me</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div class="content-panel">
          <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
              doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
              veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim
              ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
              consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque
              porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
              velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore
              magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum
              exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi
              consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit
              esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo
              voluptas nulla pariatur?"
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div class="row-panel">
          <p>Code Samples</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div class="content-panel">
          <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
              doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
              veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim
              ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
              consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque
              porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
              velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore
              magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum
              exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi
              consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit
              esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo
              voluptas nulla pariatur?"
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div class="row-panel">
          <p>Sample Apps</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div class="content-panel">
          <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
              doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
              veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim
              ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
              consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque
              porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
              velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore
              magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum
              exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi
              consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit
              esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo
              voluptas nulla pariatur?"
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div class="row-panel">
          <p>Other Projects</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div class="content-panel">
          <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
              doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore
              veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim
              ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
              consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque
              porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
              velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore
              magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum
              exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi
              consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit
              esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo
              voluptas nulla pariatur?"
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the last piece of jQuery I attempted to use:

```
$(document).on("click", ".more", function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('p').next('.show-more').toggle();
```

});

I have updated a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tracyak13/Lrvddmsf/) to show the code in action. I need for the content-panel to slideToggle every time I select a row-panel. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can [collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) if you are using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().next().children('.content-panel').slideToggle( 800 );
```

`'.content-panel'` not actually needed but added for specificity.

Because your code structure is quite simple it's easier to just traverse up, then back down again.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/Lrvddmsf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.your-class', function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        // -
        $(this).slideUp();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        // and apply animation styles to a class or animate with a code
        $(this).slideDown();
    }

    return false;
});
```